# Is it possible to get rid of laravel_session in Set-Cookie of a request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, session-cookies, laravel-validation

I happen to notice that when I make a request to my API (written in Laravel framework), there is Set-Cookie:

```
  Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlF5SDNLeGlRRTBFSlVJbXROSEZMWlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRlZXWVJrZERJN0tPRDU1TG40MGpJeURDQjRncUFYWGk4MjRBeFhMVHc3S2w5aW8yRFc1TCt4UWUzTEJnMTRpNkpYYkV6bnZ6Yk85RWF0MGIxaVhXYkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImRmNTc0MzRkZGM1ZDg0YWZkMWZjZThjOGI4Y2FlNTI2NjRhN2JjOGU0OTVkMWEwNTMwYTNlZmYxY2Y2ODNiMzkifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 09-Jan-2015 20:49:47 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

How can I get rid of it or block my Laravel API to not use it? It is possible can add a script in that laravel_session value.

Also, how do I avoid my app to consume the cookie set by the request?

Comment: What do you mean by 'It is possible can add a script in that laravel_session value' ?

Comment: Lorenz, I meant to ask, how do I avoid my app to consume the cookie set by the request? Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable session cookies for the whole application by changing the session driver to `array`

In `app/config/session.php`:

```
'driver' => 'array'
```

Comment: Thank you Lukasgeiter,  I meant to ask, how do I avoid my app to consume the cookie set by the request?

Comment: @sireesha Joke beside. Your question does not really make sense. Cookies are not consumed. On client side, they are set, read or deleted. On server side, you can read a cookie or send it to the client (or send a deletion request). A `Set-Cookie` header should be honored by the client and server side. That is a lowlevel http requirement. Without that http cookie don't work at all.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Thank you..I am still a newbie, so my jargon would be funny :). I think I understand now.